# MYSQL Booking Avaliablity Query

Tags: mysql, join

Hello I am trying to write a MYSQL query in MYSQL Workbench that basically shows the rooms in the Room table that are free between certain check in and check out date within the Arrival_Departure Table. I believe I need a Join and a Not Between statement in my Query to achieve this but I'm not sure exactly how to write this out to achieve my desired goal. My table structure has been provided below.

```
Room: Room_ID (PK),Floor ,Price 

Arrival_Departure:Arr_Dept_ID (PK),Room_ID (FK),Check_In_Date,Check_Out_Date
```

Comment: you do want to check if the room is free between two dates right?

Comment: Yes , i want all the rooms in the room table that are not listed between the check_in and Check_out dates to display , in order to find out which rooms are free between those two periods.

Comment: Something like: `select * from Room as r inner join Arrival_Departure as a on (r.Room_ID=a.Room_Id) where a.Check_In_Date beetween date1 and date2...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing a sub-select like so would get you your results...

```
SELECT *
FROM 'Room'
WHERE Room_ID NOT IN (
  SELECT distinct(Room_ID)
  FROM 'Arrival_Departure' 
  WHERE Check_In_Date between startDate AND endDate 
  OR Check_Out_Date between startDate AND endDate
  OR (Check_In_Date < startDate AND Check_Out_Date > endDate)
)
```

**Question**

"Thanks so much this seemed to work, however could you possibly explain what the distinct function is doing because the query still seems to work without it"

**Answer**
Distinct only returns one version of each id,

If you had the following data:

```
room_id  check_in    checkout
1           4/15/15     4/16/15
2           4/15/15     4/17/15
1           4/17/15     4/19/15
3           4/18/15     4/20/15
2           4/18/15     4/19/15
1           4/20/15     4/21/15
```

Query `select room_id from table` returns:

```
room_id
1
2
1
3
2
1
```

Query `select distinct(room_id) from table` returns:

```
room_id
1
2
3
```

So, it basically eliminates duplicate data

Comment: Thanks so much this seemed to work, however could you possibly explain what the distinct function is doing because the query still seems to work without it.

Comment: I updated my response to answer your second question. If the answer is what you were looking for, I'd appreciate it if you mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Thanks but also what should i do if both dates are outside the given date range, as the query does not work properly if this happens?

Comment: `or (Check_In_Date < startDate and Check_Out_Date > endDate)`

Comment: So should the new statement look like this: WHERE Room_No NOT IN (
  SELECT distinct(Room_No)
  FROM Arrival_Departure
  WHERE Check_In_Date between '2009-06-24' and '2009-06-24' 
  OR Check_Out_Date between '2009-07-26' and '2009-07-26'
  OR Check_In_Date < '2009-06-24' and Check_Out > '2009-07-29'      )
                                                                                                                 Really Sorry about this , its just when im running this query its still not working outside the given date ranges. I appreciate all the help though.

Comment: Thanks i tested out the code in various scenarios and it seems to be working as intended now. Thanks for all the help its greatly appreciated, i have also marked your answer as accepted as well (: